# pipe 2 linux commands in c

Tags: c, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have pipe between two child processes created by same parent  (LINUX, POSIX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225810/is-it-possible-to-have-pipe-between-two-child-processes-created-by-same-parent)

I want to create a program in C. This program has to be able to do the same that piping 2 linux commands do.
For Example:
`ps aux | grep ssh`

I need to be able to do this command in a c script.

I know I can use, `fork`, `pipe`, `exec` and `dup` but I don't quite know how to put them together... 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How far have you gone? Can you show us some code you've written?

Comment: Do you just want your program to be able to work within a pipe? Then just read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`, and you automatically get that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, this should give you a brief idea of how those system calls work together.

```
void spawn(char *program,char *argv[]){    
     if(pipe(pipe_fd)==0){
          char message[]="test";
          int write_count=0;

          pid_t child_pid=vfork();

          if(child_pid>0){
               close(pipe_fd[0]); //first close the idle end
               write_count=write(pipe_fd[1],message,strlen(message));
               printf("The parent process (%d) wrote %d chars to the pipe \n",(int)getpid(),write_count);
               close(pipe_fd[1]);
          }else{
               close(pipe_fd[1]);
               dup2(pipe_fd[0],0);

               printf("The new process (%d) will execute the program %s with %s as input\n",(int)getpid(),program,message);
               execvp(program,argv);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
     }
}
```