# C++ pipe error, pipe_wait forever

Tags: c++, process, pipe

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int pipe_A[2];
    int pipe_B[2];

    pipe(pipe_A);
    pipe(pipe_B);

    pid_t pid_A, pid_B, pid_C;

    if (!(pid_A = fork())) {
        dup2(pipe_A[1], 1); /* redirect standard output to pipe_A write end */

        system("./data");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!(pid_B = fork())) {
        dup2(pipe_A[0], 0); /* redirect standard input to pipe_A read end */
        dup2(pipe_B[1], 1); /* redirect standard output to pipe_B write end */

        system("grep 5");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!(pid_C = fork())) {
        dup2(pipe_B[0], 0); /* redirect standard input to pipe_B read end */

        system("grep 2");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In which "./data" is my test sample that does:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

I tried to build a pipe according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225810/is-it-possible-to-have-pipe-between-two-child-processes-created-by-same-parent):

Apparently my program does not work. After I run my program, there will be two processes doing pipe_wait for ever (I saw that from system monitor). It seems that there are some pipes should be closed. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each child gets its own copy of the parent's file descriptors.  And `dup2` creates yet another copy.  The read side of the pipe will not return EOF until all of the copies of the write side get closed.

So after each call to `fork` + `dup2`, go ahead and `close` all four of pipe_A[0], pipe_A[1], pipe_B[0], and pipe_B[1].

Also close them in the parent after you fork all of the children.  (This not strictly necessary in your example, since they will be closed automatically when main() returns.  But I would do it anyway for cleanliness.)